# Find $\sum_{k\in S} \frac 1{2^k}$, where S is the set of numbers not divisible by 2 or 3.

Tags: number-theory, summation, contest-math

Find $\sum_{k\in S} \frac 1{2^k}$, where S is the set of numbers not divisible by 2 or 3. This is a problem from CHMMC 2010. I was able to prove that this converges by comparing it to the sum $\sum_{k\ge 1} 1/2^k$, but was unable to go any further.

Comment: Hint: Numbers in S are congruent to $_____$ mod 6.

Comment: @Did 1,5 How does that help with the problem?

Comment: Hint 2: The sum of 1/2^k over every k congruent to 1 mod 6 is $___$.

Comment: @Did Oh I see now. It is just $2.5\sum_{k\ge1} \frac 1{32^k}=\frac 5{62}$ right?

Comment: Not quite. Why 32, to begin with? Also, the sum clearly includes $1\over2$; how can it be less than $1\over2$?

Comment: @IvanNeretin $2^{6k+1}=32^k*2$, but I forgot about 1/2, so the sum should be $36\over 62$ $= 18\over31$

Comment: Check your powers of 2 again. In my book 32 is the fifth.

Comment: @IvanNeretin ok, so 5+63/126=34/63.

Comment: Now it looks OK to me.